# Encounter NotSerializableException error when using Spring MVC NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: spring-mvc, notserializableexception

I'm using Spring MVC NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, when i call "userService.addAndSendAccountActivationEmail(user, request)" from controller, i got error. But  if i don't use named parameter(like: private static final String ADD = "insert into user_(user_id, email, username, password, create_date, modified_date, status_) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"), everything work fine for me.

When this line has been called on BaseDao "jdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().update(sql, param, keyHolder)", i see nothing in "param" object.

I've added "org.springframework.jdbc" level to track, see my error log below.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserService implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Resource
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Transactional
    public void addAndSendAccountActivationEmail(User user, HttpServletRequest request) throws SystemException {
        add(user);
        // sendAccountActivationEmail(user, request);
    }
}

public class UserDao extends BaseDao {

     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UserDao(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        super(jdbcTemplate);
    }

    private static final String ADD = "insert into user_(user_id, email, username, password, create_date, modified_date, status_) values(:userId, :email, :username, :password, :createDate, :modifiedDate, :status)";

    public void add(User user) throws SystemException {
        long userId = updateForLongKey(ADD, user);
        user.setUserId(userId);
    }

}

public class BaseDao implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    protected BaseDao(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    protected <T> long updateForLongKey(final String sql,T t){
        SqlParameterSource param = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(t);
        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();  
        jdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().update(sql, param, keyHolder);
        return keyHolder.getKey().longValue();
    }
}

DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.htws.account.service.UserService.addAndSendAccountActivationEmail]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Acquired Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@6589127] for JDBC transaction
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Switching JDBC Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@6589127] to manual commit
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL update
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [insert into user_(user_id, email, username, password, create_date, modified_date, status_) values(:userId, :email, :username, :password, :createDate, :modifiedDate, :status)]
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.BeanPropertySqlParameterSource@1dafb644], value class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.BeanPropertySqlParameterSource], SQL type unknown
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - Looking up default SQLErrorCodes for DataSource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 5, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 5000, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hge16h8tu21anplw8eof|6469cee6, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge16h8tu21anplw8eof|6469cee6, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 3000, initialPoolSize -> 10, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/htws?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 1800, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 50, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 10, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]]
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - Database product name cached for DataSource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource@bd9f0537]: name is 'MySQL'
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - SQL error codes for 'MySQL' found
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator - Unable to translate SQLException with Error code '0', will now try the fallback translator
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator - Extracted SQL state class 'S1' from value 'S1009'
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@6589127]
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@6589127] after transaction
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
ERROR: com.htws.account.web.UserController - PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into user_(user_id, email, username, password, create_date, modified_date, status_) values(:userId, :email, :username, :password, :createDate, :modifiedDate, :status)]; Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into user_(user_id, email, username, password, create_date, modified_date, status_) values(:userId, :email, :username, :password, :createDate, :modifiedDate, :status)]; Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:107)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
    at com.htws.core.dao.BaseDao.updateForLongKey(BaseDao.java:34)
    at com.htws.account.dao.UserDao.add(UserDao.java:86)
    at com.htws.account.service.UserService.add(UserService.java:65)
    at com.htws.account.service.UserService.addAndSendAccountActivationEmail(UserService.java:58)
    at com.htws.account.service.UserService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$4b2f4817.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.htws.account.service.UserService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$78d9a26a.addAndSendAccountActivationEmail(<generated>)
    at com.htws.account.web.UserController.processRegister(UserController.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.invoke(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:409)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setSerializableObject(PreparedStatement.java:4412)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setObject(PreparedStatement.java:4083)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setObject(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:365)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:365)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:217)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:145)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:46)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:816)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.BeanPropertySqlParameterSource
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setSerializableObject(PreparedStatement.java:4401)
    ... 73 more
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate  instead of SqlParameterSource .

Jdbc template dont have method which uses a SqlParameterSource

Comment: I'm sure we can use SqlParameterSource for NamedParameterJdbcTemplate , it worked fine for me in my old project, don't know why it doesn't work now.